# Parse.com equivalent to Group By

Tags: android, group-by, parse-platform

I have been reading through parse forums and I gather that as of 2 years ago there was no equivalent of SQL Group By.

I'm wondering if there have been any developments on this?  I have thousands of records and I need to pull down all records in descending order of a value rating and then group them by name.

If this isn't available at present perhaps someone could suggest something I could work on instead.

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries-basic , you can have secondary sorting key, which would be equivalent of "group by".

```
query.orderByDescending("rating");
query.addAscendingOrder("name");
```

could do the trick for you .

Comment: Yes, it works, if you are having trouble with something similar, post   question with your code ...

Comment: How would we limit number of records in each such group created by above query? i want to retrieve prices of all products for recent two dates only. so im first ordering by products with secondary order index of date field. but then how to limit only recent two dates for each product type.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options generally:

1. Refactor your schema to accommodate the model
2. Run a job to aggregate your data into "snapshots"

For option 1 it means creating "afterSave" handlers that update counters etc as data changes (expensive writes, cheap reads), here's a sample in the documentation that saves a "comments" count for a Post object:

https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-aftersave

You would need to run a once-off job to set your initial counts since you already have data there (see option 2).

For option 2 you can learn more about background jobs by reading up here:

https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#jobs

Your job is allowed to run for up to 15 minutes (e.g. if it is processing insane amounts of data, or doing many things in sequence).